# Python Socket File Transfer Send -While loop error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

While loop error in client.py ,i can't download.How will i fix? I'm using Pycharm. i don't understand loop error and I've been trying for 2-3 hours.I'm trying to fixed loop error but i couldn't. Please help me.When i write file name and download error.There is no problem in the operation of the server. likewise in the client. When I just run the code, it doesn't get out of the last while loop, it always seems to download.

```
   ---------server.py-----
   import socket
   import threading
   import os

def RetrFile(name, sock):
filename = sock.recv(1024)
print(filename)
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    sock.send(b"EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename)).encode())
    userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
    if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
            sock.send(bytesToSend)
            while bytesToSend != "":
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
else:
    sock.send(b"ERR ")

sock.close()

def Main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5001

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

print("Server Started.")
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("client connedted ip:<" + str(addr) + ">")
    t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("retrThread", c))
    t.start()

s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
Main()

-------client.py-------
   import socket

def Main():
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5001

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

filename = bytearray(input("Filename? -> ").encode())
if filename != 'q':
    s.send(filename)
    data = s.recv(1024)

if data[:6].decode().rstrip().upper() == 'EXISTS':
    filesize = int(data[6:].decode().rstrip())
    message = input("File exists, " + str(filesize) + "Bytes, download? (Y/N)? -> ")
    if message == 'Y' or message == 'y':
        s.send(b'OK')
        f = open('new_' + filename.decode(), 'wb')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        totalRecv = len(data)
        f.write(data)
        i = 0
        while totalRecv < filesize:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            totalRecv += len(data)
            f.write(data)
            print("{0:.2f}".format((totalRecv / float(filesize)) * 100) + "% Done")
            print("Download Complete!")

        f.close()
    else:
        print("File Does Not Exist!")

s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
Main()
```

Comment: Can you share the data list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the client cannot download the file because it does not send files from server.
Client.py send bytes response to server.py when it makes a comparison it returns false.
The server is not sending the file because the if did not gives true.
I changed the if statement like this, probably this will give true and send the file.

```
   if userResponse == b'OK':
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
            sock.send(bytesToSend)
            while bytesToSend != "":
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
```

Comment: Thank you ,successful